# Connecting dishwasher to the waste disposal

Tags: dishwasher

Can I connect my dishwasher drain directly to the waste disposal or do I have to connect the dishwasher drain to an air gap first?

Comment: Are you using the dishwasher port on a garbage disposer?  That effectively _is_ an air gap itself.  The dishwasher then dumps into the disposer chamber and drains from there.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect above the U bend or P trap this will work. If the connection is below the U bend or P trap sewer gasses can enter the home these can be both unhealthy and explosive.